# Webpack duplicates styles in html

Tags: webpack, css-loader, webpack-style-loader

My html:

```html
<!-- head -->
<body>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

My webpack.config.js:

```js
module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.css$/,
         use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          { loader: 'css-loader' },
         ]
      },
    ],
  }
```

Dev dependecies:

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "css-loader": "^6.6.0",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
  "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
  "webpack": "^5.69.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
}
```

I'm running: webpack --mode=production or webpack --mode=development, but in html file, I see:

```html
<style></style>
<style> // Equal content </style>
```